# Code a twisted torus

Tags: twisted, pseudocode, plane

My question is part academic, so it doesn't belong here, but since I only want the code aspect of a twisted torus, I hope no one minds me posing this question here. I'm ultimately modelling what are called "Grid Cells" which are repeating patterns of activity. But what I need here is to wrap a subset of a 2D plane onto a torus such that walking in any of six directions will return one back to the starting point.

Torus Approach:
Take a SQUARE piece of paper and tape the top and bottom together to get a tube. Then tape the left and right ends of the tube to get a donut. Now if you start out in the center of the piece of paper (that is now a donut), if you travel in any of the 8 directions:

1. N
2. NE
3. E
4. SE
5. S
6. SW
7. W
8. NW

you will circle around the donut exactly once and return to your starting position.

Now if you choose a specific size for this 'square paper' lets say 10x10, then for an environment of size 100x100, even when travelling in a straight line in the environment, one would loop around the 'torus' 10 times, and return to the same point. The benefit here is that the environment can be expanded indefinitely, and the torus would react by simply circling more times

The code for this is trivial as it only involves calculating the environment coordinates, mod the width/length of the 'square paper'. The problem is that, by Pythagoras rule, The diagonal travels (NE,SE,SW,NW) will be longer than the other four directions (N,E,S,W). To deal with this we use equilateral triangles, or a hexagonal mesh such that if one travels in each of six directions, the travel will be the same distance:

Twisted Torus:
Take a piece of paper and somehow tape it together such that the distance travelled will be the same for any of the following six directions:

1. 0
2. 60
3. 120
4. 180
5. 240
6. 300

The problem is I can't find any straight forward explanation of how to make a twisted torus. I have looked over the following and they are too vague for me

[Twisted Torus Video](http://www.janinebennett.org/torus-twisted%20torus.html)

[Instructions On Making a TT](http://www.math.csusb.edu/reu/jb04.pdf)

[Grid Cells Based on TT I](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17696288)

[Grid Cells Based on TT II](http://www.mendeley.com/research/model-grid-cells-based-path-integration-mechanism/)

Can anyone provide me with a small snippet of code as to how I could implement this? Cheers

*EDIT* What I need is to map continuous space onto a twisted torus such that travelling in any of the six directions in the environment will periodically return back to the same location in the 'square paper'.

Comment: I don't understand how this is a programming problem.  What does the code need to do?

Comment: Paper part is easy: take a strip of paper, grasp an end in each hand, twist one end 180 degrees, tape the ends together..  as for the code.. have you considered exploring the wonders of linked lists?

Comment: the problem is that I'm mapping a continuous element (space) so I can't imagine using linked lists. I see where the confusion arises, let me update the question

Comment: I'm just struggling as to how to wrap space around from its representation on a torus to its representation on a twisted torus.

Comment: I realize that the english word "twisted" means exactly what you are talking about, but you probably want a different tag - see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/twisted/info :)